# A field $K$ versus a field $K$ as an extension of $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

A theorem in my abstract algebra book:

> "Let $K$ be a field. $\operatorname{Aut}(K)$ is a group under composition and $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ is a subgroup"

where $K/F$ is an extension of fields. My question is aren't $K$ and $K/F$ the same thing?

Comment: $\text{Aut}(K/F)$ is the collection of automorphisms of $K$ which fix $F$.

Answer (score 2):

$\operatorname{Aut}(K/F)$ is notation for the automorphisms of $K$ which fix the subfield $F$. More precisely, $\operatorname{Aut}(K/F) = \{\alpha \in \operatorname{Aut}(K) \mid \alpha(x) = x\ \forall\ x \in F\}$.